# mongoDB read performance difference between one to many models and normalized models

Tags: mongodb, nosql, one-to-many

here are 2 possibilities for a note taking database that will have multiple notes for multiple users to keep track of

1.

```
[
  {
    "_id": "abcd",
    "userInfo": {
      "userID": "1",
      "notes": [
        {
          "noteID": "1",
          "text": "123"
        },
        {
          "noteID": "2",
          "text": "456"
        },
        {
          "noteID": "3",
          "text": "789"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "_id": "efgh",
    "userInfo": {
      "userID": "2",
      "notes": [
        {
          "noteID": "1",
          "text": "123"
        },
        {
          "noteID": "2",
          "text": "456"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

And the 2nd option:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "abcd",
    "userID": "1",
    "noteID": "1",
    "text": "123"
  },
  {
    "_id": "efgh",
    "userID": "1",
    "noteID": "2",
    "text": "456"
  },
  {
    "_id": "ijkl",
    "userID": "1",
    "noteID": "3",
    "text": "789"
  },
  {
    "_id": "mnop",
    "userID": "2",
    "noteID": "1",
    "text": "123"
  },
  {
    "_id": "wxyz",
    "userID": "2",
    "noteID": "2",
    "text": "123"
  }
]
```

I'd expect 1 to have a much better performance when it comes to loading notes for a single user(if the user has a ton of notes). However, 2nd option is much better when modifying and adding individual notes.

Comment: For writes/updates, performance is going to depend on whether the storage-engine is WiredTiger or MMAP (https://www.percona.com/blog/2019/01/03/mongodb-engines-mmapv1-vs-wiredtiger/). Read performance should be comparable (and generally neglibible compared to network round trip) if documents are in memory, but nested documents should be much quicker if paging from disk is required.